# Chrome browser default setting wont stop using scroll bars except when running my code

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller, resize

I've been asked to make my website resize and adjust without scroll bars as it is also used on mobiles (i.e. Make it Responsive). The problem is a puzzle and is probably something straight forward but I've been Googling for an hour and haven't found an answer.

I changed the sizing in my HTML code to percentages instead of fixed sizes and replaced some styling with CSS classes. This worked and when I ran it in Chrome and IE it worked fine with the content adjusting when the browser is resized. However, when I deployed it in mobile, it just appeared the same as before with scroll bars. I went back to my code and ran it again and it worked when I ran the deployed site in the same browser but when I tried the same in a new browser it went back to scroll bars.

It works normally in IE but in Chrome and edge it only works if I compile in that browser first. My code works but obviously whatever is causing it to revert with a new browser I need to fix. Is this a browser setting or do I need to make a change in my CSS?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **vw** as unit instead of **%** or **px** for text. And max-width and max height in **%** instead of **px** for image.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and also deleted my cache and cookies and it now works

Comment: You're welcome @user616076 . Hope I will get more chances to help you again and thanks for accepting my answer.